# How to set google spreadsheet circular dependency with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, circular-dependency

Okay I have wrote a function in apps script which is basically copy my sheet and then create a new spreadsheet and paste copied sheet into it.

so my problem is that copied sheet has "if formula" in particular column which worked with circular dependency for adding a date to cell based on checkbox in other column
but when script copied that sheet to other spreadsheet this dependency removed by default.

so, is there any way to set circular dependency with apps script so I can add that line into my code.

Comment: Finally Spending little more time on "https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview", I have figured out how to tackle this problem there is other class method called. 
       .setIterativeCalculationEnabled(true)
        .setMaxIterativeCalculationCycles(1)

Comment: Can you contribute, as an answer, how have you solved it? Thanks.

Comment: @emel yes, I can but I wonder can i add answer to my own question cause if I put script direct into comment here I  guess this will look messy..

Comment: As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). StackOverflow encourage people to answer their own questions. If you have any doubt in how to post your answer, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See [answer]...

Answer (score 0):

Finally Spending little more time on "developers.google.com/apps-script/overview", I have figured out how to tackle this problem there is other class method called..

.setIterativeCalculationEnabled(true)
.setMaxIterativeCalculationCycles(1)

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName")  //sheet name which u want to copy.
  
    var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByID('ID')  //Targeted Spreadsheet
    ws.copyTo(ss2).setName("AnyName")        //give a name

    ss2.setIterativeCalculationEnabled(true)  //set cicular dependency enable
    ss2.setMaxIterativeCalculationCycles(1)  // set iteration (1-1000) as per your choice
  }
 }
```